# ArrayFormula working for some formulas but not others

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This ArrayFormula works:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(F:F); ""; E:E*G:G))
```

*(it does a simple calculation and fill with it all the rows that are not empty)*

This formula also works:

```
=(E1/$J$1*G1)+((1-(E1/$J$1))*$K$1)
```

*(it does a calculation for a weighted sort)*

But the ArrayFormula version of that last formula doesn't work as expected:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B:B=""; ""; (E1/$J$1*G1)+((1-(E1/$J$1))*$K$1)))
```

It doesn't give an error and it fills the correct rows, but it shows a 1 as a result for all rows (not the correct result, only one of the rows should show the 1).

Any ideas of what could be happening or how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="";; (E:E/J1*G:G)+((1-(E:E/J1))*K1)))
```